# Old Mac Pro with consistent, mysterious ailment

Tags: hardware, mac-pro

**"MacPro 8-core", aka "8x", aka "MacPro2,1", from 2007-8.**

Frequent syndrome with always the same two symptoms together: at the end of boot sequence, right when desktop is supposed to display, monitor goes dark and USB mouse can't move, but *can* click. Symptoms always happen together.

Many SMC (and nvram) resets, tests from different startup disks, Apple Software Diagnostic (both the EFI and the OS versions) passing all tests, different mice, etc. Reseated graphics card, RAM, airport and bluetooth.

While the problem is happening I control with Apple Remote Desktop, so that's how I know the mouse can click (*but not move! weird!*) and the OS is up and running while monitor is dark, etc.  In this state system report sees no monitor.  But again this is not just a display issue.

And if the startup finishes normally, then monitor stays on, and mouse moves, and all work indefinitely until shutdown/restart.

Wondering if someone here has insight with this particular, peculiar clue.

Comment: First thought, it might be a video card issue, if you have a spare you could try that. And as much as I hate to say it, Macs don't last forever. It is *possible* that something else related to the system board, RAM, drives, etc. is failing. You could start by removing various installed devices and see if symptoms change. EG less RAM, unplug an optical drive, try a new boot drive. Anything you can reasonably do and still boot the system.

Comment: Thanks for weighing in.  What's strange is that the display issue is always accompanied by a mouse issue (as described).  That makes me wonder about power. And what's infuriating is how intermittent it is.

Comment: Most of my job would not be possible without Google. But the other 10-20% is the thinking process involved in weighing the options and dealing with intermittent issues. It's a bitch to troubleshoot a problem that only happens now and then... sigh...

Comment: I've never tried this from a 2,1 but it works for my old 3,1 - running the Apple Hardware Test from USB stick, using this resource at GitHub - https://github.com/upekkha/AppleHardwareTest

Comment: Done. All tests passed, as mentioned above. Well, actually, I used Apple Apple Software Diagnostics which is much more thorough, but this is a cool link to have, thanks.

Comment: Diagnostics is only supposed to be available on 2012 & newer machines. idk how it would run or know what to look for on an old 2,1.

Comment: Just to be clear, Apple Software Diagnostic goes way, way back.  AHT is newer.

Comment: Ah, OK, don't know that - guess they changed the name, then years later changed it back to something similar… just to catch me out a decade later ;-)

Comment: ASD and AHT are two different things. Sorry if that was unclear.  ASD was supposed to be for AASP only but it's readily available.